# wordpress delete user by id

Tags: wordpress

i am currently trying to allow a wordpress uer to delete there own entry from the database.

At the moment i have a form which when is submitted throws out a js alert confirming they wish to proceed. once they click ok, they are then directed to a page with the follwoing code:

```
<?php $user_id = $current_user->ID ;  wp_delete_user($user_id) ; ?>
```

You will now be redirected to the homepage.

">

For some reason this isnt working. any ideas what it could be? no errors are getting thrown out, and the meta refresh carries on as normal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers Danyo

EDIT: Just noticed the meta refresh isnt showing, but should be located under the message "You will now be redirected to the homepage."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe WP functions are subject to the same permission restrictions as the admin area. That said, I don't think *anyone* can delete an account (not even their own). In fact, I'm not even sure you *can* delete your own account if you *were* an admin.

[This guy](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/user-self-delete/trunk/user_self_delete.php) got around it by running a SQL query, which should work, but can get kind of messy. As far as I can tell, this plugin will delete the user from the "users" table, but not any of the user's posts. Depending on how you want to handle this, custom-build your own solution based on this one.